# Tableau- Data should be displayed based on the user selected values

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following table.
**Input:**

```
Prd_no Prd_Name Fiscal_month sales
123     XXX      012015     10000
123     XXX      022015     999
124     yyy      022015     20000
125     ZZZ      122015     30000
```

From this table, I will give the user fiscal_month prompt.
Based on the month user selected, sales should be displayed for the selected month and previous month sales.
For Example, if he has chosen 022015 then sales for 022015 and then sales for 012015 should be displayed.

**Output:**

```
           Fiscal month
           012015   021015
Sales       10000    999
```

I have used parameters and calculated fields but nothing is working.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: could you please correct your output? (I suppose the second value should be "022015")... if it's so, 999 is related just to prd_no 123? do you want an aggregate result or the single prd_no detail?

Comment: You could make use of [Lookup](http://breaking-bi.blogspot.in/2013/04/using-lookup-function-in-tableau.html) function instead of complex calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Create Parameter `Fiscal_Parameter` and Populate it with Month Data.Keep Type of Parameter as Integer .

Step 2 : Create Calc Field `Previous Month`

```
IF INT( [Fiscal_parameter]/10000 ) = 1 THEN 
    INT('12'+ STR(INT([Fiscal_parameter]%10000)-1)
        )
ELSE INT(
        STR(INT(([Fiscal_parameter]/10000-1)))+ 
        STR(INT([Fiscal_parameter]%10000)
        )
       )
END
```

STEP 3 : Create Calc Field `PREV MONTH SALES`

```
IF [Fiscal month] = [Previous Month] THEN [Sales] END
```

STEP 4: Create Calc Filed `CURRENT MONTH SALES`

```
IF [Fiscal_parameter] = [Fiscal month] THEN [Sales] END
```

Step 5 : In your Sheet Use `Prod Name` , `CURRENT MONTH SALES` and `PREV MONTH SALES`. **Show Parameter Control also** .

Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: Hi Minatverma, This is working fine. Thank you for the help.